# Auto Generated Angular Tests with Karma Failing

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm having trouble understanding what is going on with the .spec.ts tests that are automatically generated in Angular. They each include     `expect(component).toBeTruthy();`, which to my understanding is a very simple test to check if the component was created. But roughly half of them pass and half fail, and I cannot see any rhyme or reason as to why.

Here is an example from a header element that I can very clearly see on every single view of the app:

```
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
at <Jasmine>
at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/header-page/header-page.component.spec.ts:24:23)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

Whereas other components have what appears to be the same test, and they pass their tests for 'should create' or 'should create an instance'.

I am working through the Angular docs, but I can't find any place to start with this. Why would automatically generated tests fail? Should I be looking at each test individually? Does it makes a difference if that component is currently showing on the client's screen or not? Should I be looking at settings in the karma.conf.js file? The project runs fine with no errors. What parts of the code could I include in this post to help you answer my question?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginPageComponent } from '../login-page/login-page.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-page',
  templateUrl: './header-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header-page.component.css']
})
export class HeaderPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public loginService:LoginPageComponent) { }
  // constructor( public MyLoginService:LoginPageComponent) { 
  //   MyLoginService.isUserLoggedIn();
  // }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
<header>
  <nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div><a href="http://localhost:4200/" class="navbar-brand">Computer Store</a></div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a *ngIf="!loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/user" class="nav-link">Create User</a></li> 
      <li class="nav-item"><a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/shopmain" class="nav-link">Shop Computer Parts</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a *ngIf="!loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/loginpage" class="nav-link">Log In</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/logout" class="nav-link">LogOut</a></li>

      <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()"  href="#"  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Profile
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Update Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Purchase History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Return Items</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Store Card</a>
        </div>
      </li> -->


    </ul>


  </nav>

</header>
```

```
HeaderPageComponent > should create
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[LoginPageComponent -> LoginPageComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for LoginPageComponent!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'LoginPageComponent', 'LoginPageComponent' ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:1085:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:16955:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:16955:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:36329:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:33972:1)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:5848:1)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:21103:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.HeaderPageComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///HeaderPageComponent/ɵfac.js:5:47)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:5993:1)
    at instantiateRootComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:12819:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/header-page/header-page.component.spec.ts:24:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HeaderPageComponent } from './header-page.component';

fdescribe('HeaderPageComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderPageComponent>;
  // 

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderPageComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the codes for `header-page.component`, also try to run the test cases using `fdescribe` for that component only to confirm that you are not getting this error from other component.

Comment: please show the code of the spec.ts failing file

Comment: Rachid O, I believe the last code is the spec.ts file.  It shows the .toBeTruthy() method at the end.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where auto-generated tests were failing about half the time, and I was able to figure out why.  This is happening most likely because tests have to be setup similar to components, such as requiring the appropriate imports, and this was not done in my tests.

I was able to fix many problems by adding RouterTestingModule, and the Module in which the component sits (for example, Admin Module), and sometimes the very base module (which in my case was the App Module).

So for the TestBed, I had to insert imports, something like this:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [    // <-- include the imports 
        AppModule, 
        AdminModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ MappingTemplateEditComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```

For your case, add in the module in which login and header page components are in. And maybe App Module if you have that.  Most likely, this will not fix all of your problems, because there will be additional things you will have to do to make the tests fully set up.  But it will at least get rid of the usual suspects and get you closer to getting all tests passed.